# funtion with const pointer template type parameter not called for arguments of non-const pointer type

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, decltype

From my understanding, a const pointer function argument should be able to accept both a const and non-const pointer. In the latter case, it's illegal to modify the value through the pointer.

Supposed I have the following template functions

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
decltype(auto) plus(T1 a, T2 b) {
    return a + b;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
decltype(auto) plus(const T1* a, const T2* b) {
    return *a + *b;
}

int main() {

    int a {2}, b {3};
    std::cout << plus(a, b) << std::endl;

    int *first { new int {2} }, *second { new int {3} };

    // it seems here that the return type is deduced to be void*?

    std::cout << plus(first, second) << std::endl;
}
```

The second function call correctly calls the `plus` template function that accepts pointer arguments but deduces the return type to be `void*`

However, if I change the template signature to

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
decltype(auto) plus(T1* a, T2* b) {
    return *a + *b;
}
```

this produces the correct result.

What's going on here?

Comment: It does not call the second overload as you claim. It calls the first one which is a better match (so template partial ordering doesn't matter) and then should fail, because adding pointers is not well-defined, see https://godbolt.org/z/djBS_k

Comment: It calls the first overload. And the error message *says* that it deduced the expression to `void` but that is due to the fact that the expression is ill-formed and doesn't make sense.

Comment: @walnut is adding pointers not well defined for templates in general, or not well defined for auto type deduction?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm Two pointers can never be added in C++. It should always generate an error message.

Comment: As has already been pointed out, adding two pointers is not well-formed C++. If your compiler really accepts this code (it should not), you should report the bug to your compiler vendor…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plus(first, second)` calls the first template overload, because it is a better match.

After template argument deduction (yielding `T1 == T2 == int*` for the fist and `T1 == T2 == int` for the second) both overloads are viable. But, for each of the two parameters, the first overload only requires an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, while the second one requires lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, followed by a qualification conversion (adding `const`).

Therefore the implicit conversion sequences of both parameters are *better* for the first overload and it is therefore chosen by overload resolution. The function template partial ordering is not even considered.

Calling the first function template with `T1 == T2 == int*` is however ill-formed, because `a + b` is not allowed if both `a` and `b` are pointer types. Your compiler should already give you an error here.

---

With the alternative signature for the second template overload, it won't require the additional qualification conversion mentioned above and the implicit conversion sequences for the parameters of the two overloads will be identically.

Therefore function template partial ordering will be considered to decide which overload to choose and because the second template is more specialized than the first one, the second one will be chosen.

With `T1 == T2 == int` it will then work as expected, because `*a + *b` adds two `int`, not two pointers, yielding a return type of `int`, because `*a + *b` is a prvalue.